# ¿Por qué decimos "guiñar el ojo"?

Tags: vocabulario

Siempre he escuchado y dicho la expresión: "guiñar el ojo". Pero si buscamos la definición de guiñar:

[**guiñar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jr0mdr8)

> Voz expr. del románico occid., quizá del lat. tardío cinnus 'señal que se hace con los ojos'; cf. ceño.
>
> 1. *tr.* Cerrar un ojo momentáneamente quedando el otro abierto, a veces con disimulo por vía de señal o advertencia.
> 2. *tr*. Entornar los párpados ligeramente, por efecto de la luz o por mala visión.
> 3. *intr*. Mar. Dicho de un buque: Dar guiñadas por mal gobierno, marejada u otra causa, o darlas a propósito por medio del timón.
> 4. *prnl*. Hacerse guiños o señas con los ojos.
> 5. *prnl. germ.* Irse, huir.

Tomando la primera acepción, que es la que me interesa, vemos que ya la definición implica que lo que se cierra es un ojo.

Busqué la palabra "guiñó" en el CORDE y encontré que al menos el uso que yo he escuchado también se ha usado en la literatura:

> Le hizo un gesto a Sabato y le guiñó un ojo, como diciendo qué tal iba eso.
>
> <sub>Ernesto Sábato, 1974, Abaddón el exterminador</sub>

---

> Cuando él se retiró del comedor, la rubia volvió a mirarlo e, indudablemente, guiñó un ojo.
>
> <sub>Adolfo Bioy Casares, 1962, El gran Serafín</sub>

---

> Pedro Ramírez guiñó el ojo y sonrió en señal de haberle comprendido.
>
> <sub>Francisco Navarro Villoslada, Doña Toda de Larrea o la madre de la Excelenta</sub>

¿No sería suficiente el verbo guiñar (con su adecuada conjugación)? ¿Por qué hay que especificar que se guiña un ojo si eso ya es implícito?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"guiñar" requiere el objeto directo "ojo" simplemente porque es transitivo (como indica la abreviatura *tr.*). La definición que da el diccionario no debe tomarse como un sustituto perfecto de la propia palabra. Podríamos decir que la definición es algo redundante: de hecho, ¿qué más podemos guiñar que no sea un ojo? Pero, al mismo tiempo, si no se especificara "ojo", la definición podría inducirnos a creer que se puede ¡guiñar la boca!

Un ejemplo parecido -- pero no exactamente igual porque la palabra es un poco más versátil -- que muestra la redundancia de la definición como un medio para clarificar el significado es la definición de [fruncir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IXC6f67). En su primera acepción, encontramos:

> 1. tr. Arrugar la frente y las cejas en señal de desabrimiento o de ira.

Nuevamente, nos encontramos con un verbo transitivo y con la necesidad de decir:

- fruncir el ceño

si deseamos que "fruncir" tenga el sentido explicitado por la definición.

Conclusión 1: las definiciones muchas veces no son sinónimos de las palabras definidas y no deben interpretarse como palabras o frases que podrían reemplazarlas.

Conclusión 2: para definir ciertas palabras específicas, a veces son necesarios ciertos vocablos que vuelven a aparecer en contexto junto con los términos definidos. Esto no debe tomarse como descalificatorio de la definición sino como una ayuda que nos da el diccionario para que entendamos el uso restringido de esas palabras.

Nota: Ciertos diccionarios son más precisos que el DRAE y podemos encontrarnos con algo como:

```
(dicho de un ojo / referido a un ojo) cerrarlo momentáneamente
```